# Loading GeoJSON with polygon in OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, openlayers, geojson, import

I am trying to load GeoJSON in OpenLayers, however, the polygon isn't visible on the map. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>Gminy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([18, 53]),
          zoom: 10
        })
      });
      var urlGminy = 'map.geojson';
      var warstwaGminy = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
              url: urlGminy,
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
          })
      });
      map.addLayer(warstwaGminy);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: https://ibb.co/w6PQL9f

Comment: Please edit your question and add error text. Anyway, this is typical CORS security error when trying to load GeoJSON from local file system. This is prevented in most browsers for security reasons.

Comment: You can't access geojson file like static html. You have to use a web server (IIS, Apache Tomcat v.s.)